# Find a condition on 

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, density-function

> Let $X_k$ ($1 \leqslant k \leqslant n$) be real valued random variables with corresponding probability
> density function $f_{X_k}$ ($1 \leqslant k \leqslant n$), respectively. Define the joint density function
> $f_{X_1,\cdots,X_n}(x_1, \cdots, x_n) =C_1f_{X_1}(x_1)+ \cdots +C_nf_{X_n}(x_n)$
> $\space$
> (I) Find a condition on the n tuple $C = (C_1, · · · ,C_n)$.

This is what I did :
By the definition of joint density and its imposed condition, we know that:
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \dots \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x_1, \cdots, x_k)dx_1,\cdots,dx_k=1$$

Since the joint density function $f_{X_1,\cdots,X_n}(x_1, \cdots, x_n) =C_1f_{X_1}(x_1)+ \cdots +C_nf_{X_n}(x_n)$ is given, then:

\begin{align}& \Longrightarrow \int_{-\infty}^\infty \dots \int_{-\infty}^\infty (C_1f_{X_1}(x_1)+ \cdots +C_nf_{X_n}(x_n))dx_1,\cdots,dx_n=1\\
& \Longrightarrow \int_{-\infty}^\infty C_1f_{X_1}(x_1) dx_1+ \cdots +\int_{-\infty}^\infty C_nf_{X_n}(x_n))dx_n=1\\
& \Longrightarrow C_1\int_{-\infty}^\infty f_{X_1}(x_1) +\cdots + C_n \int_{-\infty}^\infty f_{X_n}(x_n) dx_n=1\\
& \Longrightarrow \boxed{C_1\cdots + C_n =1, \quad C_{1,\cdots n} \in \mathbb{R}}\\ 
\end{align}
Is it right?

Comment: Is it right to separate the integral like the second line with the right arrow?

Comment: Ah, you're right. You aren't allowed to do that. I thought each $f_{X_i}$ was a density function on $\mathbb R^n$. The integral is linear, but what happens when you evaluate the integral?

Comment: I see. if I integrate then I will get the marginal cdf $F_{X_k}$

Comment: @bitesizebo I was wondering if  the marginal cdf $F_{X_k}(x_k)$  equals to 1

Comment: From the definition you have, I don't see how it's possible for that to be a joint density function. No matter the choice of $C_i$, you'll end up with $\infty$ or 0. I don't see how you can normalise it.

Comment: no...not the density function but the distribution function

Comment: Are you sure you've copied the question correctly? Because as it currently is, there is no condition on $C$ which works.

Comment: Yep that is the question. that's why I found weird as well lol